# Unable to see comments in javascript files generated by TypeScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have created a TypeScript(.ts) file. Which upon save generates a minified JavScript file and a normal(readable) JavaScript file. All this works fine. But the comments I have added is TypeScript file is not visible in auto-generated JavaScript file. Since you cannot debug a TypeScript file (to add breakpoint, one need to use JavaScript file) and comments are not available in JavaScript file, I have to switch between .TS file and .JS file while debugging. **Is there  way to tell TypeScript, not to remove the comments user have added?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have WebEssentials installed, you can set this in the WebEssentials Options:
[image]

If you do not have [WebEssentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) installed, stop what you are doing and go install it first from NuGet.  This is a great extension that will add all kinds of helpful features for web development.

Comment: HI Joel, Thank you for reply. I changed the setting and now I can see the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `--comments` switch on the command-line to preserve comments.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I am not sure I understand you. I am not using any command-line utility. I just create TypeScript file in Visual Studio 2012 and I save it. As soon as I save the file it generate JavaScript file which does not have the comments. I am using '//' to add comments.

Comment: You'll have to edit the project file. Right-click to "Unload" it, right-click again to edit it. If you're using 0.8.2.0 you'll see an XML section at the bottom with a bunch of `TypeScript` options (should be self explanatory); if you're using 0.8.1.1 or before you'll just have to go to the bottom where `tsc.exe` gets invoked and change the commandline there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have installed web essentials and with that its easy to generate comments in JS file. I think the command you suggested also does the same thing but I find it easy to do it via IDE. I am voting up for another correct reply.

Answer (score 1):

## 0.8.2.0

If you created a TypeScript project with version 0.8.2.0 of the TypeScript Visual Studio extension (the latest version), you'll find there is an option in the project file for this:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES3</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

By default it is false, but you can just switch it to true:

```xml
<TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
```

To edit this setting, you need to right-click on the project and select "Unload", then right-click on it again and hit "Edit". These settings are at the bottom of the file you will edit.

When you have changed the setting, right-click on the project again and hit "Re-load" and you'll be up and running again.

## Previous Versions

In previous versions (if you created the project in a previous version, if you later updated to 0.8.2.0), you'll have to fiddle with the command, but the process is almost the same.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot;  @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

Change it to this:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc&quot; --comments @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
```

Once again, to edit this setting, you need to right-click on the project and select "Unload", then right-click on it again and hit "Edit". These settings are at the bottom of the file you will edit.

When you have changed the setting, right-click on the project again and hit "Re-load" and you'll be up and running again.