# strip comments when compiling TypeScript to JS - option to do so in tools via webessentials missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I cannot find the option to keep / strip comments when compiling typescript as suggested here : [Unable to see comments in javascript files generated by TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639559/unable-to-see-comments-in-javascript-files-generated-by-typescript)

[here are my options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLV4z.png) in visual studio 2012

How can I configure my type script compiler to strip comments in the resulting Javascrip

Comment: I havent had VS 2012 installed for a while, but if you have Update 2 or later (I think) then the TypeScript settings are probably an option in the project properties (right click on the project, select properties).

Comment: thanks @FredrikLjung. I got update 4 and no typescript settings in project properties at all as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this in the project settings.

> Project > Properties > TypeScript Build

If your project pre-dates this change, you can add the following to your project file manually. This usually also kicks the project settings into life so you can edit it in the normal place once you have added it manually once.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>True</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The `TypeScriptRemoveComments` in particular is the bit you are interested in, but you should add the whole block and then edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks steve, which file would this be in? I got a website project originally upgraded from vs 2005...I dont have an explicit project file

Comment: In that case I recommend transferring it into a new 'HTML with TypeScript project' - a pain I know - but should be quick and easy :)

Comment: You can leave the files in place and drop the empty project file into the root folder, then "show hidden files" and include them in the empty project.

Comment: i added such a project, i still cannot see anything like TypeScript  Build in that project's properties

Comment: Hmm. I'm starting to wonder about VS2012 support. I don't have a copy to test. A last resort could be to add a post-build event to call the compiler with your preferred settings.